# Python compilation : Will there be any different between clang and gcc compiled python

Tags: python, gcc, clang

Because of change in OS environment, I am forced to use clang compiled python. Before this change, I used python compiled by gcc.

After moving to clang compiled python, application performance is dropped by 10 %.  Can change in compiler cause this ?

Comment: `Can change in compiler cause this ?` Possibly, yes. How did you benchmark to conclude that clang version is 10% slower?

Comment: Had timed a standalone python application. This application does disk read writes.